# how to reduce the font size while reducing the page size in browser using css3

Tags: css

How to reduce the text font size based on browser page size ,while minimize the page font size have to be reduced ,how can I achieve this in CSS3?

Comment: Use JPEG format instead of HTML :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the new [css viewport units](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths).

Eg:

```
div {
font-size: 4vw;
}
```

...Which means that the font-size will be 4% of the viewport width

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/BQjdt/)** - resize the page and see how the font-size changes!

Here is a good [css-tricks article](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) about using viewport units with font-size

Browser compatability is also quite good nowadays - [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)